# What does [:3] mean?

Tags: terminology, kittens-game

In the census menu, in front of each and every kitten there is `[:3]`. What is this and what does it mean?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

:3 is a common internet "smiley" for a cat-face.

Not sure if urbandictionary links are cool around here, so here's a big warning/disclaimer:  the linked page shouldn't have anything bad on it, but it **is** a link to [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%3A3), so clicker beware!

Comment: Oh, serious? That's a bummer :(. Well, this is my first kitten game, I wasn't aware of that :P

Comment: What's wrong with that site? Does it have malware?

Comment: @NewWorld Not AFAIK, but it has word definitions that are often NSFW (e.g. if a word has a vulgar meaning or a vulgar way to describe its meaning, you'll probably find it there). I think this is likely what gatherer818 was concerned about.

Comment: @NewWorld it is a decent source if you're looking for the meaning of slang words, but it would be ill advised to look up your own name.

Comment: @NewWorld Tim has it exactly right.  The site can be very...  unpredictable as far as the "rating" of the content.  A link that looks like it should be G or PG can turn out to be a very high "R" rating with no warning, if you get my meaning.

Answer (score 23):

:3 denotes a cat's face smiley.

Comment: Appropriate profile pic

Comment: Obviously an expert on this subject.

Comment: @NReilingh Ah yes, my cat 'Cube', he was the one who told me the answer, all credit goes to him!

Answer (score 5):

I think this image will explain

[image: A cat in a box]